# How to insert the contents of a file in the middle of text in `--data-binary` using `curl`?

Tags: curl

> How to insert the contents of a file in the middle of text in `--data-binary` using `curl`?

I want to insert the contents of a binary file in the middle of `--data-binary`, e.g. `--data-binary='abc@FILEdef'`, and have `curl` update the `Content-Length` header accordingly.

However, the preceding example doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

The only way I can think of is to prepend/append the text to the `FILE` beforehand, but this is rather cumbersome for large amounts of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this without having to generate a temporary file first, is to simply generate the POST data for curl on stdin. For example:

```
(printf "beginning\n" && cat $filename && printf "trailer\n") | curl --data-binary @- $url
```

Comment: Thanks @DanielStenberg. I really need this, because sometimes I copy a huge POST body from a proxy tool (e.g. Burp) that I need to replay using a different (binary) file payload using `curl`. Since you are the creator of Curl, why does the help menu for e.g. `--data` list it as `POST` data, when in fact, is is also used for `PUT` etc.?

Comment: Because `--data`  makes a POST unless you override the method curl uses with `-X`. The standard way to do PUT is with `-T`.

Comment: Thank you, I know it's off-topic, but I would change the help text for `--data` then to something along the lines of "... request body ... (implies POST)".

Comment: It says **Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server** in the first line already. How can you think it doesn't use POST?

Comment: Indeed, I think it uses POST. It's just, by reading that sentence it make me think I can't use `--data` for PUT or WevDAV.

Comment: That sounds more like it should mention `--request, -X` there somehow...